# NHibernate fluent mapping to an entity property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a table called "Customers" and in this table there are store and office address. In the code there is a Customer class with two properties that are of type `Address` (one for `StoreAddress` and `OfficeAddress`).

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual string Email {get; set;}
    public virtual Address StoreAddress {get; set;}
    public virtual Address OfficeAddress {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 {get; set;}
    public string Address2 {get; set;}
    public string State {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string Zip  {get; set;}
}
```

I can map items that are not of an entity type Address but not sure how to map to another entity property within the customer entity?..

```
Table("Customers");
Schema("dbo);
Id(x => x.ID).Column("CustomerId");
Map(x => x.Name);
Map(x => x.Email);
```

How would I be able to map to my `StoreAddress` and `OfficeAddress` from the table Customers table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [component mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components):

```
Component(x => StoreAddress).ColumnPrefix("StoreAddress");
Component(x => OfficeAddress).ColumnPrefix("OfficeAddress");
```

Then create a component map for Address type:

```
public class AddressMap : ComponentMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        //map properterties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, I understand your missing point, we can use:

#### [References / many-to-one](http://References%20/%20many-to-one)

> References is for creating many-to-one relationships between two entities, and is applied on the "many side." You're referencing a single other entity, so you use the References method. #HasMany / one-to-many is the "other side" of the References relationship, and gets applied on the "one side."

```
Table("Customers");
Schema("dbo);
Id(x => x.ID).Column("CustomerId");
Map(x => x.Name);
Map(x => x.Email);
// this is the fluent way for many-to-one
References(x => x.StoreAddress);
References(x => x.OfficeAddress);
```

The complete overview of the `References()` syntax could be found here: [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) *(by Adam Bar)* - which is about mapping-by-code, but provides comparison with fluent syntax *(the second half of the post)*